# Why doesn't water inside a glass enter a straw when you close the top of the straw before putting it inside the glass?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Why doesn't water inside a glass enter a straw when you close the top of the straw before putting it inside the glass. Shouldn't the atmospheric and pressure of water push the water into the straw since I would assume that the pressure inside of the straw is the same as atmospheric pressure which is lesser.

Comment: Have you considered buoyancy?

Comment: Where does the air go?

Answer (score 3):

The pressure inside the straw is at atmospheric pressure before you insert the straw, but starts the rise as it is submerged in the water due to the pressure of the water. Perhaps you may think that because it is air, it should always be at atmosphere pressure. This is not true. Pressure is due to the interaction of the molecules with the boundary. What happens is that when you submerge the straw, the water pushes on the air molecules and slightly compresses the air as a response. The compression then leads to increase in the pressure of the air molecules in the straw as they are bouncing off the straw, the water, and the closed top.

So water does enter the straw, but only as much as it can compress the air.

Comment: An easy demo with a test tube (easier to keep the top sealed, the lifeguards would appreciate if it is plastic) and a swimming pool to get reasonable pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a calculation to complement Mario Figueroa's answer. Suppose that the straw is 20 cm long, and that the lower end is submerged 10 cm under water. The water pressure at the bottom of the straw is therefore greater than atmospheric by $h\rho g= 0.10\ \text m\times 1000\ \text {kg m}^{-3}\times 9.8 \ \text{N kg}^{-1} = 0.98$ kPa.

The pressure of the trapped air in the straw *was* atmospheric, that is approximately 101 kPa, so submerging the straw with its top end sealed raises the air pressure inside it by about 1%, causing the volume to reduce by about 1%, according to Boyle's law [$P =\frac{\text {constant}}V$, so $\frac{dp}{dV}=-\frac{\text{constant}}{\ V^2}=-\frac pV\ \ $ so $\ \ \frac{\delta p}p\approx-\frac{\delta V}V$]. So the water will rise about 2 mm up the straw.

[Various niceties have been ignored, such as surface tension,  the saturated vapour pressure of water, the water level at the bottom of the air column being slightly higher that 10.0 cm, possible temperature changes of the trapped air.]